# Why do I need to rebuild the route cache to make my module work?

Tags: 8

I have a [Drupal 8 module that allows banning a user by country](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_ban).

In the module, I mimic Drupal's 7 hook_init() in the following way:

```
class IpBanSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * The user's ban value.
   */
  private $banvalue;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = array('hookInit');
    return $events;
  }

  /**
   * MyModule
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent $event
   *   The event to process.
   */
  public function hookInit(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    \Drupal::service("router.builder")->rebuild();    
    $this->iPBanSetValue();
    $this->iPBanDetermineAction();
  }


  /**
   * Function sets user's ban value (if any).
   *
   * Load the user's country code based on their IP address, then check if
   * that country is set to complete ban, read-only, or has no access
   * restrictions. We then do the same for any additional read-only or complete
   * ban IP addresses added. If the user matched a country or an IP address
   * entered, then they are shown a message and/or redirected based on complete
   * ban or read-only.
   */
  private function iPBanSetValue() {
    // If code is being run from drush, we don't want to take any action.
    if ((PHP_SAPI === "cli") && function_exists('drush_main')) {
      return;
    }    
    // If user has permission to bypass ban, set to IP_BAN_NOBAN and return
    if (\Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('ignore ip_ban')) {
      $this->banvalue = IP_BAN_NOBAN;
      return;
    }
    $test_ip = \Drupal::config('ip_ban.settings')->get('ip_ban_test_ip');
    // Grab the test IP address or the user's real address.
    $ip = empty($test_ip) ? \Drupal::request()->getClientIp() : $test_ip;
    $country_code = ip2country_get_country($ip);
    // Determine if the current user is banned or read only.
    // Individual IP complete ban trumps individual read only IP, both of which
    // trump a country setting.
    if (!isset($this->banvalue)) {
      $banvalue = (int) \Drupal::config('ip_ban.settings')->get('ip_ban_' . $country_code);
      $this->banvalue = $banvalue;
      // Check the read-only IP list.
      $readonly_ips = \Drupal::config('ip_ban.settings')->get('ip_ban_readonly_ips');
      if (!empty($readonly_ips)) {
        $ip_readonly_array = explode(PHP_EOL, $readonly_ips);
        if (in_array($ip, $ip_readonly_array)) {
          $this->$banvalue = IP_BAN_READONLY;
        }
      }
      // Check the complete ban list.
      $banned_ips = \Drupal::config('ip_ban.settings')->get('ip_ban_additional_ips');
      if (!empty($banned_ips)) {
        $ip_ban_array = explode(PHP_EOL, $banned_ips);
        if (in_array($ip, $ip_ban_array)) {
          $this->banvalue = IP_BAN_BANNED;
        }
      }
    }
    return;
  }

  public function getBanValue() {
    return $this->banvalue;
  }

  /**
   * Function determines action based on current user's ban setting.
   */
  private function iPBanDetermineAction() {
    if ($this->banvalue == IP_BAN_READONLY) {
      $uri = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
      if (($uri == 'user') || strpos($uri, 'user/') !== FALSE) {
        $path = \Drupal::config('ip_ban.settings')->get('ip_ban_readonly_path');
        $response = new RedirectResponse($path);
        $response->send();
        exit;
      }
    }
    if ($this->banvalue == IP_BAN_BANNED) {
      // Always allow access to the banned page.
      $complete_ban_path = \Drupal::config('ip_ban.settings')->get('ip_ban_completeban_path');
      if (!empty($complete_ban_path) && \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath() != \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getPathByAlias($complete_ban_path)) {
        $response = new RedirectResponse($complete_ban_path);
        $response->send();
      }
      else {
        drupal_set_message(t(\Drupal::config('ip_ban.settings')->get('ip_ban_completeban')), 'error');
      }
    }
  }

}
```

If I don't add the code `\Drupal::service("router.builder")->rebuild();` in the `hookInit()` function, the module works the first time I attempt to access a page (in that it properly redirects to the page that shows a message if the user is attempting to view the site from a banned country), but if I try to access the page a second time, it allows access.

Any thoughts as to why I need to clear the router cache with every page load?

Comment: Did you try to debug what other code runs before your event? You probably need to set a priority in `getSubscribedEvents()`. Use xdebug or the web profiler from symfony, which is included in the devel module. On a fresh install there are 38 events triggered, and most have a higher priority. And what is about anonymous requests?

Comment: I didn't try full-on debugging, but based on your suggestion, I added priority as follows: `$events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = array('hookInit', 255);` The funny thing is, it will properly redirect two or three times before "giving up". These are all anonymous requests by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the correct priority

```
$events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = array('hookInit', 255);
```

so that your event runs before other actions like caching.

This only works for logged in users. For anonymous requests you need a middleware. But the problem is, in a middleware the drupal kernel is not loaded yet.

So this could be a plan:

Use both, a middleware and an event.

In middleware block anonymous users.

An example from the Ban module:

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/ban/src/BanMiddleware.php

Or let them have access to a landing page.

There the user in the correct ip range gets a session, either by clicking on a link or automatic redirect, which gives him read-only access.

Anonymous users with a session cookie can be handled in an event with the drupal kernel loaded.

There you can handle all users that are not blocked in the middlware. Anonymous with an account and session properties or logged in with all properties of the current user.

Comment: Here's the one problem I'm having with this approach: how do I check if the user is anonymous in the middleware code?

Comment: I tried checking `if (empty($_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']['uid']))`, but we're back to square one where I'd need to clear caches every time to guarantee this works.

Comment: You can't, in middleware code you have no user object. My idea is to block in middleware ip's only, similar to the example from the ban module. Put all other code in the event.

Comment: The trick is, to give new anonymous users in the right ip range access to one landing page. That landing page will get cached, but this doesn't matter. When you assign a session, users will get through to your code in the event.

Comment: My issue is, right now to support testing, I need privileged users to be able to bypass the ban (so long as they're logged in) and ideally access their user page. Anonymous users are indeed redirected to either the ban page or the read only page designated on the admin form. Of course, I could just add a warning not to block your own country, but I'd like to get this working if possible. What do you mean by assign a session?

Comment: In production you probably want to block the ip's right away in middleware, because this is very fast and could handle an DoS attack the best. You could provide a test mode, with a token in an url query string. You can check if this query string is present and the token is correct in middleware and let the request through to the event.

Comment: To provide for an anonymous request an individual response you need a session. Otherwise it will probably be cached. Not only by Drupal and Varnish/CDN on the server side, but also by caches and proxies of ISP's on the way to the client. So I think if you want to control which anonymous users get read only access you need a session.